# Динамично повесить событие onClick

Tags: javascript

Нужно:

- Динамически создать элементы img
- Повесить на эти элементы событие 
     onClick с разными параметрами

Проблемный код:

```
function board(param)
{
    ...
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        ...
        pic.onclick = board(param1, param2);/*!!!*/
        target.appendChild(pic);
    }
}
```

Собственно, проблема в событии pic.onclick (в коде он неверен). Как видно присутствует рекурсивный вызов функции board. Но в данном виде событие срабатывает еще при создании элемента pic. Как все-таки правильно повесить событие?

Comment: param1,param2 в какой области видимости ? меняются ли они в цикле ?

Comment: param1 - строка, не меняется; param2 - меняется, является идентификатором каждого элемента для работы функции

Comment: это кстати нормально, что у вас `function board(param)` с одним параметром ? А так вроде мое решение универсально.

Comment: Да ваше универсально) а вообще это моя недопечатка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае вот так:

```
pic.onclick = (function (param1, param2) { //сделать param1,param2 принадлежащими вызываемой функции
    return function () { //на событие вешаем функцию, а не результат выполнения функции!
        board(param1, param2)
    };
})(param1, param2);
```

для улучшения чтения, делаем так:

```
function board(param) {

    function gen_handler(param1, param2) { //сделать param1,param2 принадлежащими вызываемой функции
        return function () { //возвращаем функцию, которая  будет приделана к событию.
            board(param1, param2);
        };
    }
    /*...
        .....*/
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        pic.onclick = gen_handler(param1, param2);
        target.appendChild(pic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pic.onclick = board;
```

таким образом на онклик назначается функция, а если записать ее с аргуменатми - то она будет немедленно вызвана

Comment: Хотелось бы как раз с аргументами) Есть такая возможность?